# How to revert a commit made on github web interface

Tags: github

I logged in to github.com and deleted a file.
This delete operation was commited on web interface.
But now, on my git shell this commit does not exist.
How do I revert this commit ?

Answer (score 0):

Execute "git pull" to fetch the latest commits from your remote repository, then you can use "git revert HEAD~" to revert the last commit.

Comment: is it possible to revert a commit without pulling the whole project?